# Angular Reactive Form - Nested objects within form

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups, angular2-formbuilder

I've got a working nested object on my form as follows:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  name:(),
  age:(),
  address: this.fb.group({
    city:(),
    street:()
  })
})
```

However, I want the possibility of having multiple addresses, in which case I would want the JSON to look like this:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "age": "age",
  "address":
  {
    "city": "cityA",
    "street": "streetA"
  },
  {
    "city": "cityB",
    "street": "streetB"
  }
```

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Using a FormArray of FormGroups you get some like "{name:...,age:..., address:[{city:...,street:...},{city:...,street:...}...]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid, it should be:

```
{
  name: 'name',
  age: 'age',
  address: [
    {
      city: 'cityA',
      street: 'streetA',
    },
    {
      city: 'cityB',
      street: 'streetB',
    },
  ],
}
```

`address` needs to use `FormArray`. The below code shows:

1. How to build a Reactive form with `FormArray`.
2. How to add and patch value for `FormGroup` into `FormArray`.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    name: [],
    age: [],
    address: this.fb.array([]),
  });

  this.form.patchValue(this.data);
  this.addAddress();
}

addAddress() {
  for (let address of this.data.address) {
    let group = this.fb.group({
      city: [],
      street: [],
    });

    group.patchValue(address);
    this.addresses.controls.push(group);
  }
}

get addresses(): FormArray {
  return this.form.controls.address as FormArray;
}
```

The HTML template should look as below:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>Name: <input type="text" formControlName="name" /></div>
  <div>Age: <input type="number" formControlName="age" /></div>

  <div
    *ngFor="let controls of addresses.controls; let i = index"
    formArrayName="address"
  >
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <div>City: <input type="text" formControlName="city" /></div>
      <div>Street: <input type="text" formControlName="street" /></div>
    </div>

    <hr />
  </div>
</form>
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-julpqv?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

Would suggest having a read and doing the practical by following [Angular FormArray: Complete Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/).